# Getting error on PUT "Body length 0" using net/http

Tags: json, http, docker, go, docker-registry

I am using this Go API client on my app https://github.com/heroku/docker-registry-client to interact with a docker registry using Go. The case is that internally that is having some issue when does a PUT request using the package "net/http".

When I run the following code I am getting this as error `Put url: http: ContentLength=2821 with Body length 0`. So it seems that net/http Client.Do() function is not getting the body I set at some point of the function. But as you can se right on the code below at some point I still have the JSON content that I want to send in a `[]byte`.

```
body, err := manifest.MarshalJSON()
if err != nil {
    return err
}

log.Println(string(body)) // I get the JSON data back here

req, err := http.NewRequest("PUT", url, bytes.NewReader(body))
if err != nil {
    return err
}

req.Header.Set("Content-Type", manifestV2.MediaTypeManifest)
resp, err := registry.Client.Do(req)
if resp != nil {
    defer resp.Body.Close()
}
return err
```

As far as I have digged into it, the error comes from the net/http `Client.do()` function (golang.org/src/net/http/client.go line 514), and I'd say the error is triggered from `Request.GetBody()` function (from line 591 on Client).

So still trying to go deeper and do some tests to find out what is going on here.

Any clue?

In case the error is given by the server I'll have to get something like this, but in the response body and no errors on the net/http `Client.Do()` call.

```
Content-Length: <length>
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{
    "errors:" [
        {
            "code": <error code>,
            "message": "<error message>",
            "detail": ...
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Thank you so much!

Cheers

Comment: Where specifically is the error message coming from?  As an aside, `http.NewRequest("PUT", url, bytes.NewReader(body))` is a better way to pass the body to NewRequest.

Comment: The error is not from the HTTP server, but from `net/http.Client.Do()`. Are you calling `buffer.Reset()` somewhere?

Comment: @ThunderCat As far as I have digged into it today, the error comes from the net/http `Client.do()` function (https://golang.org/src/net/http/client.go line 514), and I'd say the error is triggered from `Request.GetBody()` function (from line 591 on Client). So still trying to go deeper and do some tests to find out what is going on here. And thank you for the advice, I'll modify how I pass the request to NewRequest :)

Comment: @svsd Thank you for the hint, I could go deeper today trying to understand what happens :) (you can see the reply above where I explain where I found out today about the error) And no, I don't call `buffer.Reset()` anywhere

Comment: Is the net/http client  attempting to read the body a second time because the server responded with a redirect?  Test this by setting the [Client.CheckRedirect](https://godoc.org/net/http#Client.CheckRedirect) function.

Comment: @ThunderCat I set the `Client.CheckRedirect` function so it returns the most recent response and a nil error. But still, I got the same result, so I guess it is not following any redirect

Answer (score 0):

The issue is modified RoundTripper in  https://github.com/heroku/docker-registry-client makes a redirect call to registry after getting authentication token.when it tries to redirect call to registry ,body is empty because http.request body is a buffer and once it is read in first call,buffer becomes empty and there is no body content  to send in redirect call.

**To fix it:**

```
if req.Method == "PUT" || req.Method == "POST" {
    if req.Body != nil {
        reUseBody, _ = req.GetBody()
    }
}
```

add this in https://github.com/heroku/docker-registry-client/blob/master/registry/tokentransport.go#L17 and

```
if req.Method == "PUT" || req.Method == "POST" {
    if reUseBody != nil {
        req.Body = reUseBody
    } 
}
```

in here https://github.com/heroku/docker-registry-client/blob/master/registry/tokentransport.go#L72

and change this function signature https://github.com/heroku/docker-registry-client/blob/master/registry/tokentransport.go#L71
 to accept extra argument.

```
func (t *TokenTransport) retry(req *http.Request, token string, reUseBody io.ReadCloser)
```